# Pandas - conditional column with sliding window

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a df with two columns - timestamps and text. I'm trying to label the data with True/false (1/0) labels. The condition is, that IF the word "error" is there in the text, all entries between 3-4 hours BEFORE the entry should get a 1 label and the others 0. Eg. from a df like this:

```
time   text
15:00  a-ok
16:01  fine
17:00  kay
18:00  uhum
19:00  doin well
20:00  is error
20:05  still error
21:00  fine again
```

Should be transformed into:

```
time   text       error coming
15:00  a-ok       0
16:01  fine       1
17:00  kay        1
18:00  uhum       1
19:00  doin well  1
20:00  is error   0
20:05  still error0
21:00  fine again 0
```

I read something about sliding windows with `.rolling` but I have trouble bringing it all together.

Comment: Could it appear in many rows?

Comment: Yes. I'll modify the question to reflect it.

Comment: This is very tricky :) will give it a look later, hopefully you'll get it answered soon enought though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is convert times to timedeltas, filter timedeltas with errors and for each value create mask with `logical_or.reduce`, chain mask with inverted `m1` for avoid `error`s values and convert to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
td = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str) + ':00')

m1 = df['text'].str.contains('error')
v = td[m1]
print (v)
5   20:00:00
6   20:05:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

m2 = np.logical_or.reduce([td.between(x - pd.Timedelta(4, unit='h'), x) for x in v])
df['error coming'] = (m2 & ~m1).astype(int)
print (df)
    time         text  error coming
0  15:00         a-ok             0
1  16:01         fine             1
2  17:00          kay             1
3  18:00         uhum             1
4  19:00    doin well             1
5  20:00     is error             0
6  20:05  still error             0
7  21:00   fine again             0
```

EDIT:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
print (df)
                 time         text
0 2019-01-26 15:00:00         a-ok
1 2019-01-26 16:01:00         fine
2 2019-01-26 17:00:00          kay
3 2019-01-26 18:00:00         uhum
4 2019-01-26 19:00:00    doin well
5 2019-01-26 20:00:00     is error
6 2019-01-26 20:05:00  still error
7 2019-01-26 21:00:00   fine again

print (df.dtypes)
time    datetime64[ns]
text            object
dtype: object
```

---

```
m1 = df['text'].str.contains('error')
v = df.loc[m1, 'time']
print (v)
5   2019-01-26 20:00:00
6   2019-01-26 20:05:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

m2 = np.logical_or.reduce([df['time'].between(x - pd.Timedelta(4, unit='h'), x) for x in v])
df['error coming'] = (m2 & ~m1).astype(int)
print (df)
                 time         text  error coming
0 2019-01-26 15:00:00         a-ok             0
1 2019-01-26 16:01:00         fine             1
2 2019-01-26 17:00:00          kay             1
3 2019-01-26 18:00:00         uhum             1
4 2019-01-26 19:00:00    doin well             1
5 2019-01-26 20:00:00     is error             0
6 2019-01-26 20:05:00  still error             0
7 2019-01-26 21:00:00   fine again             0
```

Vectorized solution:

```
m1 = df['text'].str.contains('error')
v = df.loc[m1, 'time']
print (v)
5   2019-01-26 20:00:00
6   2019-01-26 20:05:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

a = v - pd.Timedelta(4, unit='h')
m = (a.values < df['time'].values[:, None]) & (v.values > df['time'].values[:, None])
df['error coming'] = (m.any(axis=1) & ~m1).astype(int)
print (df)
                 time         text  error coming
0 2019-01-26 15:00:00         a-ok             0
1 2019-01-26 16:01:00         fine             1
2 2019-01-26 17:00:00          kay             1
3 2019-01-26 18:00:00         uhum             1
4 2019-01-26 19:00:00    doin well             1
5 2019-01-26 20:00:00     is error             0
6 2019-01-26 20:05:00  still error             0
7 2019-01-26 21:00:00   fine again             0
```

Comment: @lte__ - then change `td = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str) + ':00')` to `td = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`

Comment: If I do that I get `TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns, UTC] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]` and if I do `td = pd.to_timedelta(df_full['time'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]'))` I eventually get `AttributeError: 'TimedeltaIndex' object has no attribute 'between'`... What am I missing?